# How to calculate the width of a string in justified JRTemplatePrintText?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, awt, justify

Is it possible to calculate the width of a string in a [JRTemplatePrintText](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/fill/JRTemplatePrintText.html) with the alignment "justified"?

I already tried to use `FontRenderContext` of AWT but this only worked with left aligned text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot calculate the exact width of such a text, because the width depends on the way the text is exported.